# How to reduce kjournald activity

Tags: linux

The culprit that do large write to my hard disk has been caught.

It's kjournald

One way to solve the issue is to change the file system to ext2. Is there an easy way to do so?

Another thing that can work is to increase commit time to hard disk.

What does it actually do? If I make commit time 600 seconds will my hard disk fail to write for 600 seconds?

Will it mean less journalling or just delayed journalling?

The data are mostly cache and I don't need perfect accuracy.

We don't have journalling for windows right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Ext4 mount options

### Meta data only journaling (This is default)

```
data=ordered
```

### To completely disable ext4 journaling (not recommended)

```
norecovery
noload
```

### To change commit time

```
commit=<second>
```

`commit` has a default and minimum value of 5. Increasing commit value may increase disk performance but may not reduce journaling amount.

## Applying Mount Options

In `/etc/fstab`, add them to the 4th column separate by commas

```
#<File Sys>  <Mnt Point> <Type>  <Mount Options>                             <dump> <pass>
/dev/sde1    /home5      auto    auto,noatime,noload,data=ordered,commit=10  0      0
```

For complete EXT4 mount option : https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt

Windows NTFS has journaling. It is more commonly referred as [NTFS Log](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#NTFS_Log).

Comment: I would have voted for this 10 times. Such detailed answer.